# copy rows from srce to dest ignoring records already in dest

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in two seperate databases with slightly different structures:
destTable: name, address, city, state, zip, country, email, phone, company
srceTable: company, address, city, state, zip, country, name, email, phone

When I try to use this statement:

```
INSERT INTO db1.destTable (name, address, city, state, zip, country, email, phone, company) 
SELECT company, address, city, state, zip, country, name, email, phone  
FROM db2.srceTable 
WHERE db2.srceTable.email NOT EXISTS(SELECT email  
                 FROM db1.destTable  
                 WHERE (db2.srceTable.email=db1.destTable.email)
```

I get this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'EXISTS(SELECT email FROM srceTable'` at line 4

I've tried several versions of this and replaced EXISTS with NOT IN and everything produces an error.

What's the secret to this copy? 
(oh, and I only have the email field that I worry about being a dup).

Thanks,

Pete

Comment: If possible, consider making `email` a unique index then using `INSERT IGNORE`.

Comment: I can't make email UNIQUE because not every record has an email address and I believe blank/empty email fields violate the UNIQUE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just make a unique index on the email column.

Then do INSERT IGNORE INTO ...

The records already in the destination will be silently ignored. No need for the where clause.

Comment: Oh just now realised this already suggested in comments! Oops

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the last `)` from the NOT EXISTS statement.

```
INSERT INTO db1.destTable (name, address, city, state, zip, country, email, phone, company) 
SELECT company, address, city, state, zip, country, name, email, phone  
FROM db2.srceTable 
WHERE db2.srceTable.email NOT EXISTS(SELECT email  
                 FROM db1.destTable  
                 WHERE (db2.srceTable.email=db1.destTable.email))
```

Comment: Adding the right ) did nothing, same error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXISTS ( SELECT email FROM db1.destTable' at line 4

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you were trying to use NOT IN?

```
INSERT INTO db1.destTable (name, address, city, state, zip, country, company, email, phone)
  SELECT company, address, city, state, zip, country, name, email, phone
    FROM db2.srceTable
    WHERE db2.srceTable.email NOT IN (SELECT email FROM db1.destTable)
```

Also the number of columns in your INSERT and SELECT statements were different. EDIT: OK, so the fields were subtly different in that I failed to notice the `name` in the SELECT statement. I've edited my statement so now it swaps the name and company, because I still can't understand the ordering in the original statement.

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove `db2.srceTable.email` after WHERE clause and add an `)` at the end, also reorder your SELECT fields, you can have mixed data in your columns else

```
INSERT INTO db1.destTable (name, address, city, state, zip, country, email, phone, company) 
SELECT name, address, city, state, zip, country, email, phone, company
FROM db2.srceTable 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT email  
                 FROM db1.destTable  
                 WHERE db2.srceTable.email=db1.destTable.email)
```

Comment: Why remove db2.srceTable.email from the comparison? (see comment about adding the missing ) (it did nothing)